# Can I add multiple classes to a div element? (CSS)

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to add multiple classes to a div element? I try to add the *full* and the *b* class, but it does not work.

```css
#card { 
/* default for card */
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 40px grey;
}

#card.g {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 40px grey;
}
#card.b {
    background-color: lightblue;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 40px grey;
}

#card.full{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="card" class="full" class="b">Hi!</h3>
```

I am sorry if this is a bad question, I am new to programming.

Comment: Currently it is not working because browser only renders the first class attribute.

Comment: Yes just add the different classes seperated by space.

class="full b"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, you just put the multiple classes separated by a space. if you put `class=""` twice in an element, like you did, it will disregard the second one

```css
#card { 
/* default for card */
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 15px;
    background-color: yellow;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 40px grey;
}

#card.g {
    background-color: lightgreen;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 40px grey;
}
#card.b {
    background-color: lightblue;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 40px grey;
}

#card.full{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:10px;
}
```

```html
<h3 id="card" class="full b">Hi!</h3>
```

Comment: Also U can do using jquery or javascript

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem quite nicely. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can

```
<h3 id="card" class="full b g">Hi!</h3>
```